# How can i improve performance of a scalar value function used in join clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have developed a query to process the data for a report. I had to get only one record from the history table for the selected month.

For example: These are 4 vehicles. Vehicle "1" is modified four times in November 2018 on the following dates and prices:

```
1). 05 November 2018 with price 1000
2). 15 November 2018 with price 5000
3). 25 November 2018 with price 8000
```

Now i wanted the only one record on last modified date (25 November).

I developed a database scalar function and used that function in join clause which worked perfectly with less data. Now we have some records (not too much just 100 records in history table) and the report is suffering from speed/performance issues.  I created indexes and removed sub-queries but still couldn't be much helpful.

Please see my tried scripts:

```
declare @pIntFranchiseId int = 16179;
declare @pDtFrom date = '2018-12-01';
declare @pDtTo date = '2018-12-28'; 


SELECT ba.[Id],BKAgrHistory.[BookingStart],BKAgrHistory.[BookingEnd],BKAgrHistory.[StartTime],BKAgrHistory.[EndTime]
      ,ba.[FranchiseId],BKAgrHistory.[FleetId],[BKRenterId],[IsReportGenerated],[StepsCompleted]
      ,ba.[BookingId],ba.[ReservationId],ba.[RentalAgreementId],[VehicleUsedFor],[OperatorLicence]
      ,[ClearanceCode],[ExcessAmount],[ClearanceCodeAdditionalDriv],[ExcessAmountAdditionalDriv],[IsClearanceVerified]
      ,[BKDiscount],BKAgrHistory.[AgreementStatus],[IsTravelingOutsideUk],[OtherCountries],[RentalType],[RenterType],[RenterCompanyType]
      ,[IsVehicleDelivered],[IsReturnedOnSameAddress],[PickUpAddress],[ReturnAddress],[OtherReturnAddress],[TariffId]
      ,[SpecialRateId],[IsChargeShortWeekend],[IsChargeLongWeekend],[ChargeHalfDay],[IsDamageProvided],[IsRenterAgreement]
      ,[BKIsOwnInsurance],[ExpectedMileage],BKAgrHistory.[TotalHireCharge],[BKFreeMiles],[BKExpensePerMile],[BKCollisionDamage],[BKDamage]
      ,[BKTheft],[BKOverHeight],[BKBookingNotes],[BKFleetCurrentMileage],[BKMileageOut],[BKMileageIn],[BKDamageOut],[BKDamageIn],[Condition]
      ,[AppliedRates],[Paid],[OnceInvoiced],[InterimInvoiceCount],[PBNumber],[Excess],[StatusId],[CreatedOn],[ModifiedOn],BKAgrHistory.[BookingDays]
      ,[VATPercentage],[BkOpeningHrsSurcharge],[DrivenMileage],[ParentRAId],[NetTotal],[VatTotal],[GrossTotal],[GrandInsurableRevenue]
      ,[GrandTotalWithoutExtra],[GrandInsurableRevWithoutExtra],[TariffNetPrice],[OnceMailed],[LastBookingEnd],[LastEndTime],[BkOpeningHrsSurchargeNet]
      ,[BkOpeningHrsSurchargeVat],BKAgrHistory.[DailyHireCharge],[BkNetExtraDrivenMilesExcess],[BkExtraDrivenMilesExcessVAT],[BkTotalExtraDrivenMilesExcess],[ExcessMilesDays]
      ,[BkWebWeekendSurcharge],BKAgrHistory.[InsertedUserId],BKAgrHistory.[UpdateUserId],BKAgrHistory.[InsertedDate],BKAgrHistory.[UpdatedDate],BKAgrHistory.[InsertedUserName],BKAgrHistory.[UpdatedUserName],
      [SecurityDeposit],[SecurityDepositRuleId]
  FROM [dbo].[BookingAgreements] ba
join BookingAgreementAmountHistory BKAgrHistory on BKAgrHistory.Id = dbo.[GetAgreementAmtHistoryId](@pIntFranchiseId,ba.Id,@pDtFrom,@pDtTo)
     where  
     (
         DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,BKAgrHistory.BookingStart), 0)  <= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @pDtFrom), 0)  OR
         DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,BKAgrHistory.BookingEnd), 0)  <= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @pDtFrom), 0)
     )           
     and ba.FranchiseId=@pIntFranchiseId and StatusId=1
     and ISNULL(BKAgrHistory.AgreementStatus,0) not in (0,2,6,7)
     and BKAgrHistory.FleetId in (
         select f.Id from Fleets f
          join FleetsHistory fleetHis on fleetHis.Id = dbo.[GetVehicleHistoryById](@pIntFranchiseId,BKAgrHistory.FleetId,@pDtFrom,@pDtTo)
         where fleetHis.GhostVehicle = 0 and fleetHis.CoreFleet = 1 and isnull(fleetHis.StatusId,0) in (1,4) and 
         f.Franchise_Id=@pIntFranchiseId and DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,  fleetHis.PurchaseDate), 0) <=  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @pDtTo), 0));
```

---

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetVehicleHistoryById](@franchiseId int = NULL,@fleetId int = NULL, @fromDate Date = NULL, @toDate Date = NULL)
    RETURNS  int

    AS BEGIN

    Declare @returnId int = 0;
    Select top 1 @returnId = isnull(Id,0) from FleetsHistory
    where TransactionDate =
    (Select max(TransactionDate)
    from FleetsHistory  fh
    where   fh.Franchise_Id = @franchiseId and fh.Fleet_Id = @fleetId                                       
    --group by AgreementId
    and (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, TransactionDate),0)) <= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @toDate),0))
    order by Id desc;

    Return @returnId;

    END
```

---

```
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAgreementAmtHistoryId](@franchiseId int = NULL,@agreementId int = NULL, @fromDate Date = NULL, @toDate Date = NULL)
    RETURNS  int

    AS BEGIN

    Declare @returnId int = 0;
    Select top 1 @returnId = isnull(Id,0) from BookingAgreementAmountHistory
    where TransactionDate =
    (Select max(TransactionDate)
    from BookingAgreementAmountHistory  
    where   FranchiseId = @franchiseId and AgreementId = @agreementId                                       
    --group by AgreementId
    and (DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, TransactionDate),0)) <= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @toDate),0))
    order by Id desc;

    Return @returnId;

    END
```

Comment: Avoid applying functions to columns as that will prevent indexes from being used efficiently. Refactor the date range expressions to use an exclusive date like `and TransactionDate < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @toDate),0))`. Also, note that scalar functions may cause cursor-like performance.

Comment: thank you. Can you use these function's query in above query through some derived table? I need the alternate way. can anyone help in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever else functions might do, they do not improve the performance of SQL queries.

I would suggest using `apply` with the right arguments.  It is a little hard to see what you really want, given the proliferation of queries in the question, the lack of sample data and desired results, and the disconnect between your simple question and the actual query.  But the idea would be:

```
select ba.*, baah.*
from [dbo].[BookingAgreements] ba outer apply
     (select top (1) baah.*
      from BookingAgreementAmountHistory baah
      where baah.Id = ba.FranchiseId and
            baah.AgreementStatus not in (2, 6, 7) and -- this takes care of NULL values 
            baah.<date> >= @pDtFrom and
            baah.<date> <= @pDtTo
       order by baah.<date> desc
      ) baah
where ba.FranchiseId = @pIntFranchiseId;
```

`<date>` is for the modification date that you mention at the beginning of the question.  It is quite unclear which date this actually refers to.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I try for it and respond you back

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff